# android checkbox text disappears when custom background is set

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-checkbox, textcolor

I want to make a weekly calendar, where every day is a custom checkbox with objective to look like the image bellow:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyEAT.png)

When the user clicks on a day (Monday in this case), the "background" and "button" checkbox changes as well the text color...

I made the drawables and it seems to work fine... check bellow the code:

Checkbox layout:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/selectMonday"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:button="@drawable/ic_none"
style="@style/CheckBoxBackgroundView"
android:onClick="selectDay"
android:text="@string/monday_letter"
android:gravity="center"
android:checked="true"/>
```

(the drawable "ic_none", is simple a 135x135 "transparent" image with nothing in it...)

Style (CheckBoxBackgroundView):

```
<style name="CheckBoxBackgroundView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_day_week_picker_box_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_day_week_picker_box_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_spinner_text</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Background Selector (background_day_week_picker_box_selector):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/background_day_of_week_picker_unselected" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/background_day_of_week_picker_selected" />
    </selector>
```

Background selected (background_day_of_week_picker_selected):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="@color/red_color" >
    </solid>

    <!-- view border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/transparent">
    </stroke>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

and finally the color selector (text_color_day_week_picker_box_selector):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="false"
           android:color="@color/red_color"></item>
     <item android:state_checked="true"
           android:color="@color/white"></item>
 </selector>
```

I tried this in several devices... in some, it appears like it suppose to, in others the text disappears and it looks like this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnuxt.png)

probably is coincidence, but all the devices that worked are below 5 inches...

is there anything wrong with my code that I'm not seeing? anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the text disappears, or is it just the wrong color? Instead of red try using black for `state_checked="false"`, just as an experiment.

Comment: I tried that, and I also took the 'android:textColor' away from the style and still doesn't show (the letter should stay in the default color - black)

this codes works for some of my devices, in others it doesn't... so the problem is probably in some part that some devices don't accept...

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I will test this later today and let you know if I discover anything amiss.

Comment: Which drawable folder is `ic_none` in?

Comment: First I had only in `drawable-hdpi`, now I tried put in every folder, but the result is the same... should I set a different size  for the `ic_none`?

Comment: I added an answer. Did it help?

Comment: Yes! It fixed the problem... I don't know why I started use the the blank image instead of the `"@color/transparent"`, but that solved everything! :)

thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the **135**x**135** button drawable is pushing the text out of the bounds of your CheckBox's width. Instead of using a drawable, you can just set `android:button="@color/transparent"`.

Comment: Problem fixed with this Answer!